# Can Pelican be used on shared hosting server?

Tags: pelican

We changed web hosting companies (from VPS to shared hosting server) I have been hold by the company I cannot use Jekyll with them. This leaves me looking for a static blog generator option I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Pelican to generate your site on your local workstation, you should then able to transfer the generated files to your shared hosting provider via SFTP, rsync, or whatever other file transfer options are available.

Comment: Thank-you, Justin. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Pelican it shall be.   ~Z

Answer (score 0):

Justin already answered your actual question. I only wanted to add that, to my knowledge, the same is true for Jekyll (or any static site generator): You generate everything locally and just push it to the server for publication.

Comment: Thank-you, Phil. This is good to hear. My host provider assumed I wanted to install directly on the server. A bit of miss-communication between the two of us. Again thank-you.